# Retrieving POST data from Ajax in ASP Classic

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I'm trying to simply post values with ajax/jquery and print it out in ASP classic.

When I check the network tab in developer tools it shows delete_id and tbl as posted values but they dont display in my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input#del-policy').click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var del_id = element.attr("name");
    var info = "delete_id=" + del_id + "&tbl=policies";
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?"))
    {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "admin.asp",
       data: info,
       success: function(){
         }
       });

       $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
         $(this).remove();
       });
     }
    return false;
  });
 });
</script>

<%
dim i
i = Request.Form("tbl")
Response.Write(i)
%>
```

Comment: Nope, this is not the way tha ajax should be used...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input#del-policy').click(function(){
 var element = $(this);
 var del_id = element.attr("name");
 var info = "delete_id=" + del_id + "&tbl=policies";
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?"))
{
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "admin.asp",
   data: info,
   success: function(response){
      $("#yourControlid").val(response); //This do the trick
   }
   });

   $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
     $(this).remove();
   });
 }
 return false;
 });
 });
```

#### Asumming this is `admin.asp`

```
<%
  i = Request("tbl")
  Response.Write(i)
%>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But I'm still confused. What does that change exactly because I can't figure it out..

Comment: *"Try this"* answers aren't helpful, consider expanding your answer to leave a bit more detail as to why this fixes the problem in the OPs question. Remember your answer is not just for them but for anyone who comes across this problem, so try to be descriptive and help improve the quality of the content on SO.

Comment: I'm sorry, but english is not my native language...when i reach a fair good level i can be more descriptive with my answers.